# Visual Studio Code doesn't autocomplete the filepath of my csv file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Usually while working on VSC I used to import the file like this:

1: filepath='data.csv'<-- here automatically vsc used to autocomplete this for me, but now I have to do it manually. since there is no autodetection.

then

2: df=pd.read(filepath)

Now here is the second issue:

If type this

df["column"] <- the column also vsc used to detect it automatically without me typing the whole column name, now I have to do it manually as well.

I have the feeling that this happened after the release of the 2024 Visual Studio Code Version.

I've been trying everything but is not working.

Anyone having the same issue?

Installing and re installing VSC, Intellisense, Pylance

Comment: please try to limit yourself to one question per question post. for your second question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75791097/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62624980/11107541, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76019931/11107541

Comment: Are you doing this in a notebook editor in VS Code? Also, if you suspect it being caused by an update, you can [roll back your python and pylance extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541) to test that theory out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: File->Preferences->Setting Search IntelliSense. Checkbox in User and Workspace settings near the shows file-suggestion

[image: Check out the File->preferences->setting]

Comment: Thank you Nikolai, I proceeded as you said but the checkbox is already checked, still not working.